# How important are my EASA exam scores for getting a future airline job?

Tags: career, airline-pilot, easa

I'm doing my ATPL and I hear a lot of stories about what scores you should get in your exams to get a job as soon you get the licence. Does anyone have any information about how important the exam scores really are for a future job?

Comment: I'm not sure if employers have access to the scores, but like any other "just out of diapers" jobs, if the only thing an employer has to choose between you and Joe Perfect is your test score, how do you think the employer will make that decision? May not keep you from getting a job, but it may mean the difference between working for Emirates or some run down regional...

Comment: There is no real fixed answer to this as each airline has its own requirements, but generally speaking the better your results the better your chances. As one example, Air New Zealand list their policy on their website, which focuses on the amount of times you have to resist the exam: https://careers.airnz.co.nz/explore-our-careers/career-areas/more-about-becoming-a-pilot .